# Collect stream to Map set

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the following method, which responsible to put strings into a list using java 8 streams

```java
List<String> methodNames = new ArrayList<>();
typesMapperGenerationInput.getFieldsMappersMetadata().stream()
    .map(mapMethodNameConvention)
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> methodNames));

typesMapperGenerationInput.getFieldsValueProducersMetadata().stream()
    .map(produceMethodNameConvention)
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> methodNames));

typesMapperGenerationInput.getConstantMappingsMetadata().stream()
    .map(setConstantValueMethodNameConvention)
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> methodNames));
```

What I wanna do now is to put it in a map insted of a list
I have tried to do it like this:

```java
List<String> methodNames = new ArrayList<>();
typesMapperGenerationInput.getFieldsMappersMetadata().stream()
    .map(mapMethodNameConvention)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(name -> mapMethodNameConvention, number -> 2));

typesMapperGenerationInput.getFieldsValueProducersMetadata().stream()
    .map(produceMethodNameConvention)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(name -> produceMethodNameConvention, number -> 1));

typesMapperGenerationInput.getConstantMappingsMetadata().stream()
    .map(setConstantValueMethodNameConvention)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(name -> setConstantValueMethodNameConvention, number -> 1));
```

But that doesn't accomplish what I with do get

what I wanna do is to have a map of <String, Integer>
and to keep getting the string part like in the first code sample, and if I get the string from the `getFieldsMappersMetadata` the value part of the map would be 2, otherwise it would be 1

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: you should replace `toMap` with `.collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), number -> 2))` and store them in the variable correspondingly. Reason: you have already mapped the stream to the keys you want to store in the Map.

Comment: @Naman I suggest you make an Answer of your Comment, so this page can be marked as resolved.